# App launch screen and authentication

Tags: ios

I have an app that is authenticating the user using a remote API.

Is it possible to use the launch screen to call the API and delay the launch of the initial controller? I haven't figured that one out.

Thanks

Comment: You can cheat, using a view on top of the view hierarchy that looks like your launch screen, once the auth it's done just hide it.

Comment: and i recommend to add an `UIActivityIndicatorView` to let the user know, that the app is loading.

Comment: Yeah ! You can. Just load the image when you are requesting from that API and When you get the response remove that image and callout the appropriate view.

Comment: You can also set `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:` property to show or remove the indicator of `UIApplication`

Answer (score 0):

Launch screen (a.k.a Default.png, or -568h, etc.) will automatically remove itself once app is loaded. But there is a trick.
If you want to implement such functionality you can add UIImageView (with corresponding Default.png, or -568h, etc) as a subview above your root vc. And then remove it after auth.

So the user will still see the launch screen while your app is authenticating.

Comment: That's the way I was going. I tried and the transition is pretty smooth.

Comment: Great. You can also add some animation to dismiss you fake launch screen, like fade out, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In `.h`

```
UIImageView *launchImageView;
```

In `.m`

Under `viewDiDLoad:`

```
launchImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
launchImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:YOUR_IMAGE];
[self.view addSubView:launchImageView];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]; //Network Activity Indicator if you want to show
//YOUR API GOES HERE
```

When you get the data from your API, then in the **main thread**, remove that `launchImageView`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
[launchImageView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: yes.. this is also possible through storyboard, but you can't remove it from storyboard. :P

Comment: I've used a similar approach. However imageNamed doesn't really grab the right image in some situation. The launch image asset has a total of 5 portrait versions (iOS7 2x and 4x, iOS6 1x, 2x and R4). However unlike the launch screen, a regular controller only uses 2 'versions'